# Where to store login attempts and current login status, cookies or sessions?

Tags: php, mysql, session, cookies

Note: this question is on where to store **login attempts and current login status**.

I'm building a web application where users will be required to register to acquire authentication details for which to use when logging in to the system, but I'm a total newbie at security.

And I want a user to login only once per session, so a user must not have more than one existing successful authentication i.e can not sign in from both computer a and computer b at the same time or when already a successful authentication of the same user exists or was not logged out.

I think I need to track the user's location, log in attempts and current log in status; in order to act accordingly. 
I'm seeking your advice on what to use between cookies and sessions, how to track the user's location and more suggestions are welcome.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: In most cases, a cookie will store your session ID. Seems kind of a silly distinction.

Answer (score 3):

None of these.
You have to employ a database to accomplish your needs.
You have to store the current session id, login attempts and login status in the database.
Dunno what is location though.

While cookies should be used for the authorization itself, to transfer the session id between a server and a client.

Comment: Thank you for the idea. By location I meant country, city or town of the user who is logging in.

Comment: @Anthony in theory. in practice you'll never use anything else. anyway, this question is on the different matter.

Comment: @Anthony you are using cookies to store the session id on the **client**. Where it's hard to find a database, you know.

Comment: @Anthony you are confusing the client and the server. My statement is about a client while yours about a server. You cannot use a database to store a cookie on a client. That's why.

Comment: @Anthony by the way, it means that you are using cookies as well :)

Comment: @Anthony 1. By telling me that you are using a database you ARE confusing a client and a server. 2. Let's discuss my beliefs after you showing me an example of a service that is using anything else.

Comment: @Anthony this question has been asked and answered a century ago, at a time when you just babbled happily in your stroller and I am in my right mind yet and hardly confuse anything. If you don't understand what a cookie is, then for the goodness sake don't bug me with your silly demands. This is a q and a service, so just go ask a question using the appropriate form.

Comment: @Anthony I edited my answer so it won't confuse you anymore. I hope.

Comment: @Anthony like your other confusions here, an "additional" cookie exists in your imagination only. So go question your imagination, not my answer. Good luck

Comment: Then why have you been using the plural of cookie in your statements? ...........

Answer (score 1):

The main difference between **cookies** and **sessions** is that cookies are stored in the user's browser, and sessions are not. This difference determines what each is best used for.

One should go for **cookies** to store something that we want to know when the user returns to the web page in future (eg. remember me on this computer check box on login pages uses cookies to remember the user when he returns).
**Sessions** should be used to remember something for that particular browser session (like the user name, to display on every page or where ever needed).

Good read :

- [Why you probably shouldn't use cookies to store session data](http://wonko.com/post/why-you-probably-shouldnt-use-cookies-to-store-session-data)

Comment: Okay. So in simple terms if I wanted to include the remember me checkbox on the my login form, I will have to set a cookie for whichever person, checked and they didn't log out, or does it still store the details even if someone hit the log out button?

Answer (score 1):

From what I know, you can not track and compare sessions on the server to check for active connections for the same "authenticated" user.  I presume you track your user login and password in the database, and then once they authenticate you set a session variable to track their current login on a given end user device.

The best way I can imagine (aside from regular glitches of disconnects, users not logging off, etc) would be to have a table in your database to track logins and status:

- User ID
- IP Address (pulled from headers/browser)
- last login timestamp (UTC)
- Current log in status (boolean)
- Last known server session value

Once that is in place you can create contingencies:

- log me out from a logged in device if I authenticate successfully again somewhere else by having the server destroy the session stored in the database and replacing it with the new device's active session
- check for IP Address upon authentication and either lock out user, or use above method to log out remote session

You get the idea I hope.

Comment: I do get the idea and it's so helpful. However somewhere you said "Once they authenticate you set a session variable to track their current login on a given and user device" which i think is a great idea but whenever a user is authenticated it means the system will create a new session id and hence allowing a user to log in multiple times at once.