# How to track login attempts in Java/Tomcat and display message that user is locked out after x tries?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, authentication, servlets

My question is somewhat similar to the two questions below but they don't quite offer the solution for my particular situation, I think:

[How to track login attempts using HttpSession in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13694239/how-to-track-login-attempts-using-httpsession-in-java)

[Should I use cookies or sessions to store login attempts and current login status?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5447571/should-i-use-cookies-or-sessions-to-store-login-attempts-and-current-login-statu)

Here's the skinny.

A user logs in, via a JSP webpage. The form submits to a login authentication servlet created by an external vendor. **I cannot modify this servlet nor can I programmatically authenticate the server.** It's not that I don't how to modify it but, for business reasons, I cannot touch it.

The user's credentials are maintained on a database that is specific to this same vendor. If the login attempt fails, it returns to the user back to the login page.

With all that said, I need to display a message to the user, if they have been locked out. The lock out mechanism is controlled by the vendor, so I don't have to worry about that. The user is locked out after x attempts. So, say the user is locked out by the system after 10 login attempts. It'd be relatively easy to display the message if I had control of the login authentication servlet. My idea is to create a servlet filter which maps to the login authentication servlet. However, because servlet filters fire *before* the mapped servlet/url is processed, I can only verify the user up to x-1 attempts.

On the xth attempt, the filter fires *before* the authentication servlet checks the user's credentials. Say the user's credentials are incorrect. The user would be kicked back to the login page. Now what am I to do? **I can't assume the user is using one username.** Maybe he has tried some combination of a few username/password credentials to login. Essentially, what I'm running into is the user would have to have x+1 failed login attempts to display a lockout message. I.e., a user is technically locked out after 10 attempts but the lockout message will only show up after 11 or more attempts.

I'm not quite sure what can I do to show a lockout message after x attempts with all these restrictions.

**Just to be perfectly clear, in this proposed servlet filter, a vendor DB table, of which I did not create and have no control over, tracks the number of attempts per username.** So, in order for me to validate that the user is locked out, I look at this table. I need the username entered at the login page, of course, to do so. **I'm not aggregating login attempts in the code.** A database table takes care of this.

My problem is I need to display a message on the login page after x attempts for a particular username. With the servlet filter, firing before the login authentication servlet, I can only display it after x+1 attempts for a particular username. Again, I can't assume the person sitting at the computer is using one username or the same person has been sitting there the whole time. There could be multiple login attempts from different usernames at the same computer.

If there really is no feasible way, other than add the lock out validation in the vendor's servlet, then I will try to push for that. Otherwise, I'm not sure what I can do.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Did u have a look at this post. does not have the full code put something to look into. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13694239/how-to-track-login-attempts-using-httpsession-in-java

Comment: I did. Unfortunately, I don't think it's applicable here. I have no control over the login auth servlet. It's a blackbox. If successful, it kicks to an index page. If it fails, it kick back to the login page. These actions are all controlled by the servlet. I also can't assume the user is trying to login with 1 account. Say numattempts=10. He may try 8 times per user over 3 users and the system would not lock out those accounts because each account gets locked out after 10 tries per account, not 8.

Comment: I updated the question to try and be more clear about the situation. I apologize if my previous explanation was not clear or too vague.

Answer (score 1):

How does the redirect work if there is a login failure?  If it sends a HTTP 401 then you can check that after you call chain.doFilter but before you return from your own doFilter.  Store the number of failed logins in the HttpSession and boot them out when the number reaches 10;

Comment: Wow, that's an interesting dea. Well, it appears the vendor's servlet sends an HTTP 302 upon login failure, redirecting to the login page. Would what you proposed still work and, if so, how?

Comment: Well, that's unfortunate because that same code is likely sent in the event of a successful login too.  You'd have to examine **where** they are being redirected and that could get ugly.  In that case check the response.getHeader("Location") value after you do the chain.doFilter().  That's rather hack-o-rific but I'm not sure of another way.

Comment: It is unfortunate, yes. But I will try as you say, check where they are being redirected to. What I don't quite understand is how to check after `chain.doFilter()`. Perhaps you can elaborate. I had thought `chain.doFilter(request, response)` is the last code you write in the `doFilter` function of a filter. Or are you saying to create a second filter and place it right after the first filter?

Comment: Yes, usually chain.doFilter() is the last method in your own doFilter().  But it doesn't have to be and the HttpServletResponse class will be filled in after you call chain.doFilter().  It will be filled in with, in this case, a response.getStatus() of 302 and a response.getHeader("Location") of something like "/login" or "firstPage.jsp" (obviously I'm guessing here).

Comment: Ahh, I think I understand now. Interesting. I wasn't aware something like this was possible. I'll have to try it out and report my findings. I appreciate your help with this! I thought of running a filter on the login page itself, in addition to a filter for the vendor's servlet. The filter on the login page would return the username logged in, if the user was redirected from the vendor's servlet (the vendor's servlet does not send user data back to the login page). Seems messy and may not work. Your proposal seems much better. Thank you, again.

Comment: FYI: I'm using an older Servlet spec, version 2.4. I created a wrapper to return response headers, documented here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35739145/servlet-response-wrapper-to-add-getheadernames-and-getheaders-methods-to-servet). Response status comes back, it seems, but no response headers. As such, I cannot determine the redirect page. If my wrapper and filter look OK, then maybe it's the vendor's servlet. I can try writing another filter but this one will act on the login page.